# Check in delete files/renamed files/moved files to TFS using command line

Tags: tfs

I'm basically doing something like dropbox but using TFS.

Everything works smooth except when I delete a file in side my workspace folder.

Let's say I deleted a file test.txt in my local workspace (already mapped to TFS); when I use `tf add $/Test/Doc /recursive`, it's saying no pending change detected.

But if I use `tf status $/Test/Doc /recursive`, I could see the delete change actually is detected. 
Similar case happen when I do rename a file or move a file into another folder under Doc.

Is there any way to add this detected changes to pending change and use `tf checkin $/Test/Doc /recursive` to checkin?

I tried to use `tfpt online /deletes` also, but with error **"This command doesn't support local workspaces."**

If this problem can be solved without using `tfpt` will be better. Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not delete the files in the local workspace directly. This may cause some unkonwn troubles. If you want to delete the files in source control , you can use this command `tf delete (local mapping path)\test.txt` (Make sure you have enough permissions). Then check in your changes.

For your situation:

First, you can undo your pending changes use [undo command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c72skhw4(v=vs.120).aspx).

- If you want to delete the test.txt, use the command mentioned above.
- If you still need it, you can remapp it from sever to your local
  worksapce.

---

update
[image]

Comment: So you mean it is not quite possible to use TFS similar to dropbox by just using TFS command? If really cannot, I may need to search some other way. Anyway, thanks for your kind reply.

Comment: Meanwhile, can I delete the file first, then use tf delete (mapping)\test.txt  after the deletion?

Comment: No your can't, the command will retrun ''file could not be found in your local workspace" . I'm not  familiar with dropbox. If you mean you want to use source control in the windows file explorer. You may need to try tfs power tools https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/898a828a-af00-42c6-bbb2-530dc7b8f2e1 (this is for tfs2015 and there is for tfs 2013 and so on..) After installing this, you can delete file or rename, move file  in the local workspace. Then right click the file or project select team foundation server select what you want just like the screenshot updated above