# tf.exe checkin does not find any pending changes

Tags: command-line, tfs, checkin

I'm trying a simple TFS 2015 checkin automation. I have a local workspace mapped to a local folder. In that folder, I added some files and deleted one. What I want is to checkin those changes

I run this command

```
tf.exe checkin <folder> /recursive
```

The result (unexpected) is "no pending changes"

If I run the following command

```
tx.exe status <folder>
```

I get the list of changes expected.

If I look in Visual Studio source code explorer, I cannot see my changes but if I try to add items in the TFS folder, I can see new files.

Can you help me to understand how I can automate this checkin scenario?

EDIT : based on this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34172812/check-in-delete-files-renamed-files-moved-files-to-tfs-using-command-line), it seems it is not possible to achieve this with local workspace. Can someone confirm?

Comment: With running `tf status` command, your files should under "detected changes" not "changes", actually there are not "*real pending changes*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run "tf add" command to add these files into Pending Changes before run "tf checkin" command:

```
tf add * /recursive
```